# Can't extend C drive, Is it to do with where its located?

Tags: partitioning

I want to extend my C drive since its full and I can't download anything but it won't let me extend it. Does it have to do with where it is?

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course it has to do with that layout. You need 3rd party tools to move it to the left before thinking about extending. And have backups frits because it's a risky operation.

Comment: do you really need to extend drive C:? ... what is wrong with creating drive E: in the empty space?

Comment: @jsotola For one you now can't organize your files neatly and every time you're looking for something you have to look in two locations

Comment: why not? ... the My Documents folder can be put anywhere